# Load html file in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Hi I am trying to load a html file using ShellApi, achieving good load html file but the problem is when the html file is local pictures using img src = test.jpg, my idea would be to load the html file so that the images look, but when I load the following code the images are not seen but the html code is well

```
ShellExecute (0, 'open', 'explorer', PChar ('file :/ / /' + dir + 'test.html'),
     nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: I have not got the faintest clue what your question is. Please try again. And what made you try to open HTML in explorer?!

Comment: I don't know if this helps in any way (no clue about your question here either), but you may want to see this: http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=161351

Comment: I want to do is load an html file using shellexecute, but the problem is that the html file local images are not seen when loading internet explorer

Comment: Maybe you should be invoking 'iexplore' for the browser.  Or just "execute" the .html file in your ShellExecute in place of 'explorer' and and have the default browser open it?

Comment: You are not opening internet explorer.

Comment: Indeed, `explorer.exe` is the Windows Explorer, it's what comes with Windows to browse files, shows your taskbar, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a file with the default verb, in the associated program, like this:

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(FileName), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running the exe from?
If you run it from the same folder as the startup HTML, then this should work.

I use this method to create auto-run CD's for HTML.
I put my startup exe (in my case "start.exe") in the root of the CD, along with 
the startup HTML and autorun.inf.

If you run from any other folder, links to other pages, graphics etc. will be lost.